# Mapping страницы

Tags: java, html, spring

Можете подсказать где я не правильно замепил страницу

```
package com.IK.notes.Controllers;

import com.IK.notes.Models.Post;
import com.IK.notes.Repo.PostRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;

@Controller
public class MainController
{
    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String notes(Model model)
    {
        Iterable<Post> posts = postRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("posts",posts);
        return "notes";
    }


    @PostMapping("/")
    public String notePostAdd(@RequestParam String title, @RequestParam String mtext, Model model)
    {
        Post post = new Post(title, mtext);
        postRepository.save(post);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @GetMapping("/notes/${id}/edit")
    public String notesEdit (@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Model model)
    {
        if(!postRepository.existsById(id))
        {
            return "notes";
        }
        Optional <Post> post = postRepository.findById(id);
        ArrayList<Post> res = new ArrayList<>();
        post.ifPresent(res::add);
        model.addAttribute("post", res);
        return "notesedit";
    }

}
```

а именно ошибка возникает из-за этого

```
@GetMapping("/notes/${id}/edit")
    public String notesEdit (@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Model model)
    {
        if(!postRepository.existsById(id))
        {
            return "notes";
        }
        Optional <Post> post = postRepository.findById(id);
        ArrayList<Post> res = new ArrayList<>();
        post.ifPresent(res::add);
        model.addAttribute("post", res);
        return "notesedit";
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приложите NotesApplication еще пожалуйста

Comment: Посмотрите, возможно у вас было запущено более одного экземпляра приложения (выключили идёю, оставив работающим приложение). В этом случае найдите и убейте все инстансы томкатов...ну или тупо перезагрузитесь и попробуйте. Если ошибка не будет воспроизводиться после этого или отпишитесь тут или удалите вопрос (не знаю, понадобится кому такой ответ на него...)